# Reading multiple resource from jar file

Tags: url, jar

I have jar file containing two folders each with a bunch of files (and possibly some other files in the root):

```
myjar.jar
 > sub1
    > file1.txt
    > file2.txt
    > file3.txt
    > ...
 > sub2
    > file1.txt
    > file2.txt
    > file3.txt
    > ...
 > otherfile.txt
```

I have another project that depends on myjar.jar that contains an application that needs to read all the resources/text file and for each resource convert them into a string. Therefore I would like to do

```
URL url = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sub1");
// Somehow iterate all sub urls and convert to string
```

Any good suggestion for doing this? One approach could be:

```
String scheme = url.getProtocol();
if (!"jar".equals(scheme)) {
  // Hm who if we simply want to run from the workspace???
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported scheme: " + scheme);
}
JarURLConnection con = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
JarFile archive = con.getJarFile();
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = archive.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
  if (entry.getName().startsWith(folder)) {
    System.out.println(entry.getName());
  }
}
```

but I would like to avoid this low-level code.

Comment: Have a resource listing all the resources, so you don't need discovery...

Comment: Have text file as resource, giving the path to all other resources you need to read. Read this file, iterate on its lines. Avoid introspection. Such file should be easy to generate at build time.